# Issue in loading kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I have elasticsearch,logstash and kibana 4 installed. but when I hit Kibana 4 url like [kibana IP:5601], I get following shard failure errors from kibana 4 discover page.

[image]

Any pointers why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your `kibana.yml` is correctly configured to hit your Elasticsearch cluster? And is your ES cluster up and running (i.e. what does `curl -XGET yourhost:9200/` give you)?

Comment: Check the console of your browser for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Aah .. Got it.
Someone changed the default index pattern which was incorrect and thus it got stuck in searching for that.
Corrected the pattern and it's fixed.